# Jquery .load() one step behind

Tags: jquery, spring

I have a section on a webpage that is generated like this.

```
<table>
    <c:forEach items="${personList}" var="person">
        <tr>
            <td>
            </td>
            <td>
                <h2 style="text-align:left;">${person.reviewName}</h2>              
                <h2 style="text-align:right;">by ${person.name}</h2>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="text-align:right;">
                <img src="<c:url value="/resources/${person.id}.jpg" />" >
            </td>
            <td>
                ${person.review}
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div id="${person.id}" class="comment">comments</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="ins${person.id}">
            <td>

            </td>
            <td id="comments${person.id}" style="display:none">
            <div id="ins${person.id}">
                <table>
                        <c:forEach items="${person.comments}" var="comment">
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    ${comment} 
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </c:forEach>
                </table>
                Add Comment:
                <textarea id="comment${person.id}"></textarea>
                <button onClick="addComment(${person.id})">add Comment</button>
            </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</table>
```

I'm trying to use JQuery.load() to instantly update the comments section when a new comment is added like this.

```
function addComment(id) {
    $.getJSON("addComment", {id:id, comment:$("#comment" + id).val()});
    $("#comments2").load("home #ins2");
}
```

The problem is when the when I click to add the comment it only displays the comment I previously added, meaning the comments section is always one comment behind. If I load the page directly after adding the comment it displays as it should. Another strange thing is that when I do add the comment a blank line is inserted a the top of the comments, which isn't there/goes away when I load the page directly.

I thought this might be some kind of cache problem so tried to turn it off using

```
$.ajaxSetup ({
    cache: false
});
```

However this made no difference.

I'm really at a dead end with this. Is it something to do with the section I'm pulling with load() being a forEach tag?

Comment: You could (and probably should) modify the functionality so that you perform a single AJAX call which both adds the new comment and then returns the HTML for all of the comments. Or you could add the new comment and return only the HTML for the new one, then append that to the relevant part of your page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to load your comments in the `success` callback of the `getJSON` method to wait the end of the `getJSON` call before reload your `div`.

```
function addComment(id) {
    $.getJSON("addComment", {id:id, comment:$("#comment" + id).val()}, function(){
        $("#comments2").load("home #ins2");
    });
}
```

Comment: Really? How come? What's the difference?

Comment: getJSON is a shorthand method of $.ajax. By default, javascript doesn't wait the result of the $.ajax method before executing the next statement.

Comment: @user1584500 `jQuery.getJSON()` is a wrapper for an AJAX call, so that and the `.load()` AJAX call run at the same time. Since they're both asynchronous you can't be guaranteed that they'll complete in the order that you begin them, but in this case you need the first one to update the comments before you can retrieve them.

Comment: OK, that makes sense, but now the page doesn't update at all unless I load it directly. Does this mean the getJSON() call isn't completing?

Comment: Could be, the best thing to do is to apply a loading layer durring div update and remove it in the success callback. But for your test, just add a console.log('loaded') and survey in the console F12 to be notified when the getJSON call is finished

Comment: No output to the console. The call isn't completing.

Comment: @user1584500 The first thing to check is whether the response is valid JSON. If it's not then, even though the call is successfully handled by the server, the success callback won't be executed.

Comment: Just had to get the response returning in valid JSON to check this was the correct answer.